# When is $\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ whenever $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

$\mathbb{Z}_m$ represents a cyclic group of order $m$.

I have no knowledge of rings and fields. I only know group theory.

In general, I would like to know how to prove that $2$ groups are isomorphic to each other? Is the only way to solve it is to show a bijective homomorphism?

Comment: see also [Prove that $\mathbb Z_{m}\times\mathbb Z_{n} \cong \mathbb Z_{mn}$ implies $\gcd(m,n)=1$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/375348/264)

Comment: If you have a textbook, this fact is commonly exploited to prove the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and is likely proved there.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375348/prove-that-mathbb-z-m-times-mathbb-z-n-cong-mathbb-z-mn-implies-gcd This also helps.