# Show that $Z_5 \times Z_7$ and $Z_{35}$ are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

> Show that $Z_5 \times Z_7$ and $Z_{35}$ are isomorphic.

I tried $$f(a,b) = 7[a]+ [b]$$

where $a \in Z_5\ and\ b \in Z_7$

Is this Correct ?

**

- Edit :

** It is similar to this question :

[When is $\mathbb{Z}_m\times\mathbb{Z}_n$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316672/when-is-mathbbz-m-times-mathbbz-n-isomorphic-to-mathbbz-mn?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I just read it but can you check if the approach I mentioned to the question is correct ?

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: Can you think of an element of the product that has order $35$?

Comment: And [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316672/when-is-mathbbz-m-times-mathbbz-n-isomorphic-to-mathbbz-mn?noredirect=1&lq=1), linked to it.

Comment: @EthanBolker I guess what you are proposing is that Order of (1,1) element in $Z_5 * Z_7$ is 35. hence it is cyclic Group with Order 35. There exists isomorphism between two cyclic groups of same order.
Correct ?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I just read it on wikipedia. It seems the same.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for pointing out. Please check the edit.