# Show that $\mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_5$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{60}$

Tags: group-theory

There is a theorem that states that $\mathbb Z_{m} \times \mathbb Z_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{mn}$ if the $gcd(m,n) = 1$ because otherwise $\mathbb Z_{m} \times \mathbb Z_n$ would not be cyclic.  Would deriving that proof and saying that $\mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_5$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{60}$ by stating that $gdc(12,5) = 1$ be a sufficient proof?

Comment: Yes, the proof is more general.

Comment: You're "specializing" a theorem, i.e. giving values to $n,m$ for which the theorem is valid, whence the conclusion is correct.

Comment: Yes, that's an application of said theorem.  [There is a more thorough explanation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375348/prove-that-mathbb-z-m-times-mathbb-z-n-cong-mathbb-z-mn-implies-gcd) about when, and when not (and why not), the product of cyclic groups is cyclic.